# Gunicorn flask makes thread/gevent spawn sequential

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, gevent

I was running a thread based application using flask in apache.
For some reason I moved it to gunicorn with class as gevent. Thread was not working properly.
Then I tried using gevent spawn and added gevent.sleep if I run the application as python app.py it is working good. If i run as gunicorn with gevent class spawn runs sequentially.

Basically I have to call 9 different api parallely and based on the response will decide the output.